# How to append set that has most intersection elements to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to iterate over two lists of sets with one list only containing 1 set and append the set to the list that has the biggest intersection til all sets are appended.For each new element in order_of_sets the procedure should be repeated. The algorithm should function like a greedy algorithm.

```
      s1=set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
      s2=set([1,3,56,8,9])
      s3=set([1,4,5,6,7,8,10,22,23,24,25])
      s4=set([7,8,9,10,23,14,22,23,24,30,56])
      list_of_sets=[s2,s3,s4]
      order_of_sets=[s1]

      for x in list_of_set:
          for y in order_of_sets:
             if len(x.intersection(y))==max[len(x.intersection(y))]:
                 order_of_lists.append(y)
                 list_of_sets.remove(y)
```

What i want in the end is:

```
order_of_sets=[s1,s3,s4,s2]
```

Maybe i can define a function that evaluates the length of the intersection but i dont know how.

Comment: What is your intended output? Could you write this in your description, please.

Comment: "has the biggest intersection" with what other set?

Comment: The set in order of sets which would be s1. I want to add the set from list_of_sets that has the biggest intersection with s1. This would be s3. And after that i want the next to be done with set 3. The biggest intersection would be between s3 and s4.

Comment: and once you have `s3` in `order_of_sets`, why would s4 be appended next ? also because it has the biggest intersection with s1 ? with s3 ? or else ?

Comment: With s3.So allways adding the set that has the largest intersection(element wise) with the last added set

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} # in python 3 this set notation is easier on the eyes
s2 = {1,3,56,8,9}
s3 = {1,4,5,6,7,8,10,22,23,24,25}
s4 = {7,8,9,10,23,14,22,23,24,30,56}

list_of_sets = [s2,s3,s4]
order_of_sets = [s1]

while list_of_sets:
    best_set = max(list_of_sets, key=lambda s: len(s.intersection(order_of_sets[-1]))) # gets the set from list_of_sets having the largest intersection with the last set from order_of_sets
    list_of_sets.remove(best_set)
    order_of_sets.append(best_set)


print(order_of_sets)
```

> > > [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 22, 23, 24, 25}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 22, 23, 24, 56, 30}, {1, 3,
> > >       8, 9, 56}]

Comment: Thank you very much i will try it! I knew it would be something simple and my knowledge would be simply insufficient. What is the meaning of "[-1]" in the second line?

Comment: it gets the last item from `order_of_sets`